# Existence of differentiable matrix maps $M(3,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(3,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let's say that $M(3,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of square matrices of dimension $3*3$. Is there a neighborhood $N$ of $I_3$ on which there is a differentiable square root map $f: N \rightarrow M(3,\mathbb{R})$, with $$f(I) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &1 &0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $(f(A))^2=A$ for every $A \in N$?

Another question is as follows:
Is there a neighborhood $L$ of $I_3$ on which there is a $C'$ class function $g: L \rightarrow M(3,\mathbb{R})$, with $$g(I) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &0 &1\\ 1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $(g(B))^3=B$ for every $B \in L$?

Background: I learned that matrices can represent derivatives of multivariable functions, and have understood, for example, [Is there a general form for the derivative of a matrix to a power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553609/is-there-a-general-form-for-the-derivative-of-a-matrix-to-a-power), but I do now know how to use the conditions given by the question to answer if the questions are true or false.

edit: There is a previous possibly related question, that the Linear transformation $T: M(3,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(3,\mathbb{R}), T(B) = AB+BA$ (for a diagonal $A \in M(3,\mathbb{R})$) is invertible if the diagonal elements of $A$ satisfy a certain condition.

Comment: I don't understand your similar question, what does $g$ have to do with $f$? As defined $I≠ g(I)^2 ≠ g(I) $ so I can't make a correct guess

Comment: I meant that the problems were of similar flavor sorry for the confusion. Will edit

Comment: looks the same after your edit?

Comment: Oops! Sorry now it's OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the implicit function theorem, that is a well-known method.

i) for$f$. Let $p:X\in M_3\mapsto X^2$ and $U=diag(-1,1,1)$; then $p(U)=I_3$; the derivative of $p$ is

$Dp_X:H\in M_3\mapsto XH+HX$ and $Dp_U(H)=UH+HU$ is a sum of functions that commute.

$p$ has a local $C^{1}$ inverse from a neighborhood of $I_3$ to a neighborhood of $U$ IFF $Dp_U$ is invertible. Let $spectrum(U)=(\lambda_i)_i$.

According to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties

$spectrum(Dp_U)=\{\lambda_i+\lambda_j;i,j\}=\{-2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2\}$ and, therefore $p$ has no $C^1$ local inverse.

ii) for $g$ (in the same way).  Let $q:X\in M_3\mapsto X^3$ and $V=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$; then $q(V)=I_3$; the derivative of $q$ is

$Dq_X:H\in M_3\mapsto HX^2+XHX+X^2H$ and $Dq_V(H)=HV^2+VHV+V^2H$ is a sum of functions that commute.

$spectrum(V)=spectrum(V^2)=(\mu_i)_i=\{1,u,u^2\}$ where $u=e^{2i\pi/3}$.

Then $spectrum(Dq_V)=\{\mu_i^2+\mu_i\mu_j+\mu_j^2;i,j\}$.

With $\mu_i=1,\mu_j=u$, we obtain (at least) one zero eigenvalue and, therefore, $q$ admits no local $C^1$ inverse.

EDIT. Answer to the OP and Sally G.

If you don't know the theory of Kronecker products, then, no matter, it suffices to display elements of $\ker(Dp_U)$ and of $\ker(Dq_V)$. For example

$H=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\in\ker(Dp_U)$ and $H=diag(1,0,-1)\in\ker(Dq_V)$.

Comment: I lost you at spectrum. I went to your wiki link, but didn't find any information about adding eigenvalues. I'm not familiar with the Kronecker product, and I can't see how $spec(D_{pu})$ was calculated. Is this the only way to see that there is no local inverse?

Comment: You could also calculate a representation matrix of $\mathrm Dp(U)$ using the $3\times3$-matrices with a single 1 as an entry as a basis. You'd get a $9\times9$-matrix (since $M_3$ is a 9-dimensional space), which you can test for invertibility.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos , yes it's standard. Yet, I try never to use this presentation because it suggests that the resolution of $AX+XB^T=(A\otimes I+I\otimes B)X=C$ is in $O(n^6)$ while there are methods that solve this equation with complexity $≈20n^3$.

Comment: I wrote this in answer to @SallyG, who asked for a different approach. It wasn't meant to criticize your way. I should have @ them to be more clear.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos , you did well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about differentiable maps in general, but to test for the existence of a $C^1$-map, you can use the inverse function theorem: you're looking for a local inverse of the $C^1$-map $h:M(3,\mathbb R)\to M(3,\mathbb R),~A\mapsto A^2$ around $A_0$, where $A_0$ is one of the matrices above. Such a map exists iff $\mathrm Dh(A_0)$ is invertible. So you should test for that.

Comment: i downvoted. this shud be a comment

Comment: Sorry. Is it because it only covers a special case, or because it leaves the work of doing the actual computations to the asker?

Comment: It's because it's a comment and not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: what would I have to add to make it an answer as opposed to a comment? I gave an equivalent condition that's trivial (though tedious) to check. Would actually doing the check for op have been sufficient to make it an answer?

Comment: I thought you only dealt with a special case.

Comment: Kind of. Verbatim, they asked for a square root map. No restrictions on wether it's differentiable. The title implies that they want it to be differentiable. But the standard question in real analysis would be about $C^1$ functions. I assumed the latter of the three, without which this method won't work, so I added that as a caveat at the beginning, because I wasn't sure wether that was actually what they wanted. If such assumptions are not up to the community's standards, I'm fine with that. But I'd like to know if that's actually the issue, and not something else.

Comment: ok, sorry, I didn't really read the question or your answer. it just seemed like a comment, especially after you commented "it only covers a special case". but ill remove my downvote (and upvote since you've been nice)

Comment: I'm so sorry. I need a differentiable square root map. Added it into the question, completely my fault for not saying it before!