# Linear dependence of $3\times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VP}{V.P.}
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AC}{AC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\BB}{B}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RHO}{\rho}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\CCC}{C^1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\contt}{C}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PCC}{PC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LL}{L}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}
\newcommand{\ph}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\inth}{\Int_{-h_k}^0}
\newcommand{\teta}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
%\renewcommand{\L}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\<}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\>}{\geqslant}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits}
\newcommand{\Max}[2]{\max\limits_{#1}\brr{#2}}
\newcommand{\Min}[2]{\min\limits_{#1}\brr{#2}}
\newcommand{\Sup}{\sup\limits}
\newcommand{\Lim}[2]{\lim\limits_{#1}\br{#2}}
\newcommand{\lmin}[1]{\lambda_{\min}\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\lmax}[1]{\lambda_{\max}\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\renewcommand{\ae}{\stackrel{\mathrm{a.e.}}{=}}
\newcommand{\pc}[4]{\PCC_{#1}^{#2}\br{#3,#4}}
\newcommand{\mh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\ev}[1]{\lambda\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\bh}{\mathbf h}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbf N}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm{d}t}
\newcommand{\re}[1]{\RE\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\im}[1]{\IM\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textup{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\textup{y}}
%\newcommand{\w}{\textup{w}}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\ti}{\times}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\Mu}[1]{\mu\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\del}{\delta}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\renewcommand{\O}{\Omega}
\newcommand{\B}[2]{\BB\br{#1,#2}}
\newcommand{\Rho}[2]{\RHO\br{#1,#2}}
\newcommand{\ac}[3]{\AC_{#1}\br{#2,#3}}
\newcommand{\til}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ln}[1]{\ln\br{#1}}
\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\wD}{\widehat{\Delta}}
%\newcommand{\CC}[2]{\CCC\br{#1,#2}}
%\newcommand{\cc}[3]{\CCC_#1\br{#2,#3}}
\renewcommand{\c}[4]{\contt_{#1}^{#2}\br{#3,#4}}
\renewcommand{\L}[4]{\LL_{#1}^{#2}\br{#3,#4}}
\renewcommand{\U}[2]{\bigcup\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\brrr}[1]{\autobracket*{#1}}
\newcommand{\brr}[1]{\autobrackett*{#1}}
\newcommand{\br}[1]{\autobrackettt*{#1}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\abss*{#1}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\normm*{#1}}
\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\angless*{#1}}
$
Consider matrices $A,B\in\R^{3\ti 3}$ and identity matrix $I\in\R^{3\ti 3}$. Why matrices from the set $M=\{A^2B + ABA+BA^2,AB +BA,A^2,A,B^2,B,I\}$ are linearly dependent over $\R$?

Multiplying equation $\sum_{i=1}^7x_iM_i=0~\left(M_i\in M,~x_i\in\R\right)$ by $A$ from both sides, using Hamilton-Cayley's Theorem and reduce similar terms by setting constants $x_i$, I've obtain
$$
x_1\left(a_0\left(BA+AB\right)+A^2BA^2\right)+x_3A^4+x_4A^3+x_5AB^2A+x_7A^2=0,
$$
where $a_i\in\R,~A^3+a_2A^2+a_1A+a_0I=0.$ Also it is seen that $x_3A^4+x_4A^3+x_7A^2$ may be reduced to $bA,~b\in\R,$ but I don't understand how to deal with other summands.

Comment: I am going to write down a solution using indeed Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: Hint: consider $p(B+A)+q(B-A)$ where $p$ and $q$ are respectively the characteristic polynomials of $B+A$ and $B-A$.

Comment: @user1551 I see we are on the same wavelength...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{cases}P&:=&A^2B + ABA+BA^2\\Q&:=&AB +BA\end{cases}.$$

One can verify that

$$2P=(B+A)^3+(B-A)^3-2B^3\tag{1}$$

Cayley-Hamilton theorem applied to $A+B, A-B$ and $B$ resp. yields the following decompositions :

$$\begin{cases}(A+B)^3&=&t_1(A+B)^2-s_1(A+B)+d_1I&(a)\\
(A-B)^3&=&t_2(A-B)^2-s_2(A-B)+d_2I&(b)\\
B^3&=&t_3B^2-s_3B+d_3I&(c)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

(where - in particular - the $t_k$s are the traces and the $d_k$s the determinants).

The first two formulas can be written:

$$\begin{cases}(A+B)^3&=&t_1(A^2+B^2+Q)+s_1(A+B)+d_1I\\
(A-B)^3&=&t_2(A^2+B^2-Q)+s_2(A-B)+d_2I\end{cases}$$

Plugging these expressions into formula (1), we get:

$$2P=(t_1+t_2)(A^2+B^2)+(t_1-t_2)Q+(s_1+s_2)A+(s_1-s_2)B+(d_1+d_2)I-2B^3\tag{3}$$

Using now formula (2)(c) in (3), we obtain $P$ as a linear combination of the 6 other matrices.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Addendum : $P$ and $Q$ can be considered as differentials of functions $A \to A^3$ and $A \to A^2$ resp. "in the direction of $B$". See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556650/305862)