# Calculating derivative of a special matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

I am trying to calculate the following derivative:

Let $V,W$ be fixed $n \times n$ real matrices. Define $A(t)=e^{V+tW}$.
**What is $A'(0)$?**

I do not assume $V,W$ commute. (If they commute, it becomes trivial since then $A(t)=e^Ve^{tW}$).

**Here is the problem as I see it:**

Define $A(t)=e^{\alpha(t)}$ where $\alpha(t)$ is a (smooth) path inside $Mat(n,\mathbb{R})$.

$e^{\alpha(t)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha(t)^k}{k!} \Rightarrow (e^{\alpha(t)})'=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha(t)^k)'}{k!}$

But the formula $(\alpha^k)'=k(\alpha^{k-1})\alpha'$ is not necessarily valid if $\alpha,\alpha'$ do not commute.

Here is what happens when we try to calculate $(\alpha^2)'$:

By the Leibniz rule: $(\alpha^2)'=(\alpha \cdot \alpha)'=\alpha' \cdot \alpha + \alpha \cdot \alpha' \neq 2\alpha \cdot \alpha'$ if $\alpha,\alpha'$ do not commute.

The general formula is* $(\alpha(t)^n)'=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha(t)^{k-1}\alpha'(t)\alpha(t)^{n-k}$, so plugging this into the series formula of matrix exponential does not give you something managable, at least not immediately.

**Is there a way to claculate (or at least give an estimate of) the derivative $A'(0)$?** Can we deduce if it's zero?

---

Another approach is maybe to use the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker.E2.80.93Campbell.E2.80.93Hausdorff_formula)
but so far it didn't work for me.

---

*Note that while in general it seems that [there is no simpler closed expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470057/how-to-calculate-ft-where-fi-to-mathbbrn2-is-given-by-ft-xt) for $(\alpha^n)'$, maybe there is till hope that the specific "exponential series" with this term plugged in is tractable in some sense.

Comment: Here's one expression for the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map) which can be found using CBH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula I linked above, we come up with the answer
$$
A'(0) = \int_0^1 e^{\alpha V}We^{(1 - \alpha)V}\,d\alpha
$$
I'm not sure how helpful that is, but it's something.  Certainly, this is can be approximated in a fairly straightforward fashion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a block triangular matrix to calculate the Frechet derivative using the method of Kenney & Laub
$${\rm F}\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}X&E\\0&X\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) =  \begin{bmatrix}F&L\\0&F\end{bmatrix} $$
where $F = {\rm F}(X)$ and $$L = \lim_{h\rightarrow\,0}\, \frac{{\rm F}(X+hE)-{\rm F}(X)}{h}$$
For your particular case
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm F}(X) &= \exp(X) \cr
 X &= V \cr
 E &= W \cr
 L &= A'(0) \cr
}$$